# Whats wrong with my xlock?

Tags: linux, xlock

When I type `xlock` and press return key, I am getting the following error:

```
Unknown mode: xlock:  bad command line option "swarm"
```

What should I do? I just need the basic `xlock` screen locking functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'xlock' is trying to run the 'swarm' display mode (rather than simply blanking the screen) and is doing it wrong.

Maybe you are running

```
xlock -swarm
```

instead of

```
xlock -mode swarm
```

Or is it that your xlock hasn't been compiled/configured with the swarm screensaver on your system?

Comment: I am just typing `xlock`. I have no idea whether it is configured or not. I just want the basic `xlock` locking functionality. What should I do?

Comment: try xlock -mode dclock or (i think) xlock -mode blank